# Restore data from failed drive

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

First, I would like to apologize for my ignorance.

I need some help to retrieve data from a failed external 2.5” drive. All attempts from Win or Mac PC failed.
As a final attempt I installed lubuntu in an old laptop of mine and while searching for help I tried the following command, but with no luck.

`foremost -i /dev/sdb -v -t -all -o /dev/sdc/sdc1/media/sophocles/TARGET`
[image: terminal screenshot]

Disk “sdb” is the failed one while “sdc” is an empty disk to be used as target for data restore.
Is this possible to be achieved? Any help is mostly welcomed.

Thanks in advance
Sophocles

Comment: How did the drive fail? Is this a mechanical failure or perhaps just a corrupted partition? Reason I ask is because I’ve seen a number of situations where just a partition was accidentally deleted and 30 seconds with the `testdisk` utility resulted in a “fixed” device.

Comment: Hi Matigo, The disk failed because I had recently three continuous power failures. When I connect it to a Win or Mac, it doesn't recognize any partition. From Linux, as I mentioned I don't have any knowledge at all. SO, you propose to look how to run the testdisk command?

Comment: Installed and run testdisk. This is what I get.

Comment: # testdisk /list
Disk /dev/sda - 40 GB / 37 GiB - CHS 4864 255 63
Sector size:512
Model: FUJITSU MHT2040AH, S/N:NP0JT522NFYN, FW:846C

Disk /dev/sdb - 4000 GB / 3726 GiB - CHS 3815447 64 32
Sector size:512
Model: ST4000LM 024-2AN17V, FW:0001

Disk /dev/sda - 40 GB / 37 GiB - CHS 4864 255 63
     Partition   Start        End    Size in sectors
 1 * Linux                    0  32 33  4863 242 51   78137344
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB Recover
Disk /dev/sdb - 4000 GB / 3726 GiB - CHS 3815447 64 32
     Partition   Start        End    Size in sectors

Comment: Based on the info you provided in your question, you'll want to run `testdisk` (without any options), then choose `[Create]` a new log file, then choose the `/dev/sdb` device, then `[Proceed]`. You'll be asked about the partition type. Choose `[Intel]`, then `[Analyse]`. Some time may pass, then the system will show a list of partitions (possibly with a "No partition is bootable" message) and you can then choose to write the corrected partition info (if it is recoverable). Choose "write" and then reboot. You may have a workable device after that to back up to the new HDD via `rsync`.

Comment: Hi, a couple of hours ago, I did some reading and proceeded with the procedure you do propose, but since the disk was formatted as ExFAT (I used it in Mac and Win) the choice was EFI GPT. I continued with this option and got the message "trying alternate gpt". I continued and after 90minutes I stopped. It had checked (?) 11 out of 3815446 cylinders. If this is correct then it would take appx one year to read them all. Am I mistaken, or would I try the "Intel" option?